# How to get an input (like firstname) from user in Telegram bot?

Tags: database, telegram-bot

I am programming a telegram bot that store user profile in a database.
What is your firstname?

Who can i do this using telegram bot APIs?

Please help me.

Comment: You may need to give us some more information. What language are you using? Do you want the user to interact with your bot and want him to send your bot the information (like firstname)?

Comment: @oruckdeschel, I am using php language for programming. I want to get some info's (like firstname) using simple method like sendMessage in Telegram bot API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can do this:

```
$content    = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update     = json_decode($content, true);

$chatID         = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$userName       = $update["message"]["from"]["first_name"];
$userMessage    = $update["message"]["text"];
```

For more info take a look to: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message